# Vue Js e PokeApi

Tags: ajax, api, vue.js, axios

Atualmente estou estudando VueJs, estou usando Ajax para requisitar a API, e integrar a aplicação, porém já li em diferentes lugares sobre o Axios. Porque usar Axios e não o "$.Ajax"? É mais organizado, seguro ou simplesmente é "padrão".

Comment: `$.ajax` é jQuery.

Comment: É mais recente e menos pesado

Comment: Eu sei que é Jquery, porem gostaria de saber o motivo mas valeu pela explicação

Comment: @Vasconcelosx o axios é mais simples, tem o mesmo proposito do $ajax, a documentação recomendao axios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O principal "motivo" pra o uso do Axios é que ele é agnóstico ao sistema. Ou seja, se você estiver utilizando javascript, poderá usar o Axios seja um projeto Vue, node, angular, react, o que for.

Você aprende o Axios e pode usá-lo em qualquer projeto. Ao contrário do $.Ajax que só funciona se você instalar o jQuery.